# How do I get a user to enter a binary number and turn it into decimal?

Tags: python, binary, decimal

I am new at python, so I am making a converter from binary to decimal. I want the user to have the opportunity to enter binary and fro my program to output a number in decimal, however everytime I tried to enter it as a binary it came out as the same binary number instead of a decimal.
This is the code I have tried:

```
print ("Please input your number")
n=int(input())
bin_n = bin(n)
print(int(bin_n, 2))
```

I think maybe its the form thats being input but idk :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is entering the number in binary, use the optional `base=2` argument when converting the input, not when printing.

```
n = int(input("Please input your number: "), 2)
print(n)
```

If the user enters `1001` it will print `9`.